# How to request data from another scene in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skscene

I have 2 `SKScene`s. The first scene has 2 buttons: a male player button and a female player button. The second scene has 2 hidden images: a male player image and a female player images.

If male player is selected in `Scene1`, I want to make the male player image visible in `Scene2`, but I'm having trouble passing the data between `SKScene`s. I'm using Sprite Kit and programming in Swift. Please advise.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
// Scene1:

import SpriteKit

class Scene1: SKScene {

var malePlayer = SKSpriteNode()
var femalePlayer = SKSpriteNode()

var maleSelect = false
var femaleSelect = false

// in touches began..
if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.malePlayer {
            maleSelect = true
// then i present scene2

} else if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.femalePlayer {
            femaleSelect = true
//then i present scene2



// in scene 2:
class Scene2: SKScene {
var playerSelected: Scene1()
// did move to view
var boy = SKSpriteNode()
var girl = SKSpriteNode()

if self.playerSelected.maleSelect == true {
self.addChild(boy)
} else if self.playerSelected.femaleSelect == true {
self.addChild(girl)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, please post the relevant code. There is no mention of what language you are using. Objective-C? Swift?

Comment: i edited code for better understanding and it is for sprite kit. Scene 2 is presented but player does not appear on scene 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. Here is one example that uses `NSUserDefaults`. One reason that makes this a good option is that the selection will persist even after the app is closed and can be reloaded when the app is next opened.

To save the selection, use the following code:

```
    if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.malePlayer {

        //save the selection in NSUserDefaults
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey:"maleSelected")

        //present next scene

    } else if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.femalePlayer {

        //save the selection
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey:"maleSelected")

        //present next scene
    }
```

The value is now saved in local storage. When you need to access the selection in your other scenes, grab the value from `NSUserDefaults`:

So `Scene2` might looking something like this:

```
class Scene2: SKScene {
var playerSelected: Scene1()

// did move to view
var boy = SKSpriteNode()
var girl = SKSpriteNode()

//grab the selection value
let maleSelected = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("maleSelected")

if maleSelected == true {
self.addChild(boy)
} else {
self.addChild(girl)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In scene 2 the code:

```
var playerSelected: Scene1()
```

Creates a new instance of the scene 1 class, it does not provide a link back to your original scene 1. To access scene 1's properties you need to pass a reference to it from scene 2.

Comment: please advise what is the line of code to pass a reference from scene 2 to scene 1. thank you

Comment: @viktorm That would be highly dependant on the overall structure of your code. Scene 2 should probably not be presented from scene 1 but rather from a higher level view controller. In fact I would question why you have two scenes at all - why not have your player select sprites in a different place in the same scene? I think you need to revisit how your code is structured and how objects interact with each other, otherwise you are going to tie yourself up in circular references.